# HQL: LIKE in null relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, null, hql

I have a OneToMany relationship:

```
public class Class1{

    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;

    @OneToOne
    private Class2 object1;

}

public class Class2{
    private String attr3;    
}
```

The relationship can store null objects (I mean that an instance of Class1 can have null in object1). I want to do a complete search in all attributes so I've created this HQL query:

```
SELECT p FROM Class1 p
WHERE 
(
upper(p.attr1) LIKE :filter OR
upper(p.attr2) LIKE :filter OR
upper(p.object1.attr3) LIKE :filter
)
```

and I pass a String param in uppercase with "%" before and after:

```
query.setParameter("filter", "%"+filter.trim().toUpperCase()+"%");
```

It works OK but for the entities which have object1 = null. It never get those entities. Indeed if I remove the last condition (upper(p.object1.attr3) LIKE :filter) it works but I need to include it.

I've though I should do a LEFT JOIN with that relationship so I've tried to write it as :

```
SELECT p FROM Class1 p LEFT JOIN p.object1 AS p1
WHERE 
(
upper(p.attr1) LIKE :filter OR
upper(p.attr2) LIKE :filter OR
upper(p1.attr3) LIKE :filter
)
```

or like

```
SELECT p FROM Class1 p LEFT JOIN p.object1 AS p1
WHERE 
(
upper(p.attr1) LIKE :filter OR
upper(p.attr2) LIKE :filter OR
(p1 is not null AND upper(p1.attr3) LIKE :filter)
)
```

but without any success.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you need the values either `p1.attr3 is null` and when it is `not null` it should validate the condition. So, I am just fine tuning your last query;

```
SELECT p FROM Class1 p LEFT JOIN p.object1 AS p1
WHERE 
(
upper(p.attr1) LIKE :filter OR
upper(p.attr2) LIKE :filter OR
(p1.attr3 is null OR upper(p1.attr3) LIKE :filter)
)
```

Comment: as you can see for the comments I left the problems was another. So your answer is ok (though it's not neccesary even to check if p1 is null)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an outer join!

For example:

```
SELECT p FROM Class1 p OUTER JOIN p.object1 AS p1
   WHERE ... ;
```

Comment: I've found the problem. It wasn't that I needed an outer join. I had 2 queries one for counting and the other for selecting and I was just changing the left join in the select. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p FROM Class1 p
WHERE
upper(p.attr1) LIKE :filter OR
upper(p.attr2) LIKE :filter OR
UNION
SELECT p FROM Class1 p LEFT JOIN p.object1 AS p1
WHERE
upper(p1.attr3) LIKE :filter
```

Comment: That works, but it is inefficient. The database has to do a full sort of the result set whenever a UNION is used (that's why it is recommended to avoid UNION or prefer UNION ALL instead - but here UNION ALL would not be correct). The outer join is the efficient way of handling this case. Pls. see my response.

Comment: I've found the problem. I had 2 queries one for counting and the other for selecting and I was just changing the left join in the select. So it's not neccessary to do an union, it works without it. But thanks.